# Typescript jsdoc with annotate parameter property

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am trying to annotate a property of an object which is an argument to a function.

Specifically I want `options.length` explanation to appear in vscode when hovering over the function definition.

```js
/**
 * Memoize a function
 * @param  {(...fnArgs: T[]) => U} fn The function to memoize
 * @param  {Object} options Memoization options
 * @param  {number} options.max The max size of the LRU cache
 * @param  {number | undefined} options.length The response will be cached
 *  by the first N args, based on this value. Trailing args will still be
 *  passed to the underlying function but will be ignored during memoization.
 */
export const memo = <T, U>(
  fn: (...fnArgs: T[]) => U,
  { max, length }: { max: number; length?: number }
) => {
  const cachedArgs: T[][] = []
  const cachedValues: U[] = []
  const get = (args: T[]): U | undefined => {
    const index = cachedArgs.findIndex(x => argsAreEqual(x, args, length))
    if (index === -1) return
    onUsed(index)
    return cachedValues[index]
  }

  const set = (args: T[], value: U) => {
    cachedArgs.push(args)
    cachedValues.push(value)
  }

  const onUsed = (index: number) => {
    moveToEnd(index, cachedArgs)
    moveToEnd(index, cachedValues)
  }

  const prune = () => {
    if (cachedArgs.length >= max) {
      cachedArgs.shift()
      cachedValues.shift()
    }
  }
  return (...args: T[]) => {
    let value = get(args)
    if (value) return value
    prune()
    value = fn(...args)
    set(args, value)
    return value
  }
}
```

When hovering over the type signature I get the following

```
@param fn — The function to memoize
@param options — Memoization options
```

[image]

I've done my best to [copy from the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#typedef-callback-and-param) but it doesn't show the explanation for `options.length`.

I want it to show the explanation for how the `options.length` parameter works. How can I do this?

Bonus question, not sure how to make the generics work with jsdoc either... help with `@template` much appreciated!

Comment: I've never used this feature, but maybe you could use `@prop` or `@property` instead, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQA5Jw)?

Comment: Ah, this is a known bug apparently: [microsoft/TypeScript#24746](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24746), with possible workarounds listed in there.  Or maybe it's just not supported with TS code, as in [microsoft/TypeScript#11859](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11859)

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/ND5PVm) workaround work for you? I have no earthly idea why `Object` would prevent `@param` from working, but the linked issues seemed to indicate that would happen.

Comment: Brilliant! If you write in an answer will approve asap. Otherwise happy to take the credit myself and write the answer! hehe  @jcalz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior seems to be a known bug, whereby destructured parameters do not have their JSDoc comments displayed: [microsoft/TypeScript#24746](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24746).  I'm not really sure why, but according to [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24746), giving a `@param` a type of `Object` is equivalent to giving it a type of `any`, and you can get the behavior you want by using a different type.  In the following I change `Object` to `{}`:

```
/**
 * @param  {(...fnArgs: T[]) => U} fn
 * @param  {{}} options Memoization options
 * @param  {number} options.max The max size of the LRU cache
 * @param  {number | undefined} options.length The response will be cached
 *  by the first N args, based on this value. Trailing args will still be
 *  passed to the underlying function but will be ignored during memoization.
 */
export const memo = <T, U>(
  fn: (...fnArgs: T[]) => U,
  { max, length }: { max: number; length?: number }
) => { }
```

and your IntelliSense starts to work, at least when hovering over the function.  (I don't think it's possible to get comments when you hover over the actual identifier named `max` or `length` in your code).  Observe:

```
/* IntelliSense shows:
const memo: <T, U>(fn: (...fnArgs: T[]) => U, { max, length }: {
    max: number;
    length?: number | undefined;
}) => void   
@param fn  
@param options — Memoization options    
@param options.max — The max size of the LRU cache    
@param options.length — The response will be cached by the first N args,
  based on this value. Trailing args will still be passed to the
  underlying function but will be ignored during memoization.    
*/
```

PLEASE NOTE that this only seems to work for *TypeScript code* (like `.ts` or `.tsx`) and not *JavaScript code*.  If you do this in JavaScript, the compiler will complain about anything other than `Object` or `object`.

---

As for your bonus question, I think it should work in TypeScript just like it does in JavaScript:

```
/** 
 * @template T the arg type of fn
 * @template U the return type of fn
 * @param  {(...fnArgs: T[]) => U} fn
```

which shows me

```
/* IntelliSense shows:
const memo: <T, U>(fn: (...fnArgs: T[]) => U, { max, length }: {
    max: number;
    length?: number | undefined;
}) => void
@template — T the arg type of fn
@template — U the return type of fn 
@param fn
*/
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-aEAD83oKvsgrnA1ucDuj4FAkAAkqwkNdggBlXag3GEejnMzgRXhZUxcxanV6thGvQ6QwmC1WhzOPhAz21Z27YNRj0G9ReyA+kp+-uB7tEMNDiOTGZzRbLVbzUeuWOQaGxebgLhoLA4QAoBHhKRjpK0PDueAeXJSROJJKfZMw2JBtyM1GxX95ZOU0pBD9FVVFZkUgqT9sjUEC0iqWo-0OR0YOaOIz3aSBuj6AYhkyL9IK2IMDkPXAhGOU5wgufFbhIB5iDJQpXhQj4vl+f5MTtdRChBMEwkEKF1zhBEkVwFF0HpDEsXIvEcTuYlSXJN4DXnGk6T2BlWCZJIWTZci7i5Hk+UgAUyCFEUEk2CUQClIA)